How can I drive a MOSFET with high input capacitance using discrete transistors?
Driving MOSFETS at high frequency is hard, especially if the MOSFET has high input capacitance (as high power MOSFETS typically do).  There exist dedicated ICs to drive such MOSFETs.  However, for my understanding, and for building simpler circuits with discrete components, I'd like to drive a MOSFET with discrete transistors.
I first thought of using a BJT emitter follower to drive the MOSFET's gate: The BJT has low input capacitance, and should be able to source enough current to drive the MOSFET.  But, to my surprise, a BJT emitter follower driving a capacitive load did not behave as predicted and indeed turns out to be quite hard to analyze.
What other discrete component circuits (no ICs) could be used to drive such a MOSFET?
